# Will moment of Inertia vary with size?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I have a very basic question. What will happen to the moment of inertia if the object is uniformly shrunk? For example assume a rectangular beam and shrink all the dimensions uniformly. Will the moment of inertia change?

Comment: If you consider the definition of moment of inertia you will have your answer. It's unclear what your physics question is. Do you not understand the definition?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the moments of inertia of a beam depend on the height, width, and length of the beam.

In general, the moments of inertia depend on how mass is distributed in space, so they depends on the size and shape of the object.